# How to view the GDTR's value?

Tags: debugging, kernel, windbg

In the book "Rootkit Arsenal" page 84 (Chapter 3) mentions:

> ..., we can view the contents of the
>   target machine's descriptor registers
>   using the command with the 0x100 mask:
>   kd> rM 0x100

and a paragraph below:

> Note that the same task can be
>   accomplished by specifying the GDTR
>   components explicitly: kd> r gdtr ....

I run Windbg on my Win XP (inside VMWare) and choose the Kernel Debug -> Local.
My problem is in case of first command, windbg errors with:

> lkd> rM 0x100
>               ^ Operation not supported in current debug session 'rM 0x100'

and in the second command:

> lkd> r gdtr
>             ^ Bad register error in 'r gdtr'

Can anyone guide me ?

Comment: Please view the following stackoverflow article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28263624/can-i-print-the-gdtr-and-gdt-descriptor-under-gdb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, you can't look at registers in a local kernel debug session. LiveKD works and you can also get the address indirectly through the PCR (!pcr).

-scott

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found the solution:
Use two computers for kernel debugging instead of Local Kernel Debug.
(I used VMWare and am debugging through the COM port/named pipe)
I am thinking why this facility/feature (Local Kernel Debugging) is there if it's not complete ?

Comment: I found a solution for Local Kernel Debugging that actually WORKS
LiveKd from Mark Russinowich:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897415.aspx